# How to remove sub view in UIView

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

in my application two views are there, their names are Loginview and sampleview

this Loginview i added to `[self.view addsubview:Loginview];`

after login action. i changed self.view as `[self.view addsubview:sampleview];`

but that time also loginview is showing..

to avoid this. how to remove sub view in `self.view`?

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all the subviews:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    [view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: To remove all self.view.subviews = [NSArray array]; is better. removeFromSuperView is good for removing single specific view.